# Magento 2.1.7 - Payment Module using iframe

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm trying to create a custom payment module where the user select the payment method and than instead of redirect the user to a different page, I want to:

1. remove unnecessary elements form the page
2. show an iframe with a payment form (3rd party iframe)

I've created a basic payment module but I'm not sure how to:

1. construct the iframe dynamically (the iframe url has query params that contain cart info like total) and modify the html to show it. maybe change the page content using uicomponent? how do I get the cart data in js and this point?
2. remove html elements in "Magento/ko way".

Any insights/ideas/links?
Is there a Magento payment gateway that works that way so I can reference it for example?

Comment: this helped me understand a little better the link between php and form.html that contains ko [link](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-add-more-variable-to-window-checkoutconfig/)